# MySQL friends list two way check with only user id

Tags: mysql

How do I check if BOTH user and friend have accepted the request, having only the user_id component of the query?

This is the table;

```
CREATE TABLE friendships (
  user_id int,
  friend_id int,
  accepted boolean not null default false,
  UNIQUE KEY friend (user_id, friend_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users (id)
    ON DELETE CASCADE,
  FOREIGN KEY (friend_id) REFERENCES users (id)
    ON DELETE CASCADE );
```

This is my query;

```
'select * from friendships ' +
    'join users ' +
    'on friendships.user_id = users.id ' +
'where friendships.friend_id = ? AND accepted = true '
```

This only checks it one way and **therefore this is still valid when returning a 'friend', even though one user has not accepted**;

```
user_id: 1, friend_id: 2, accepted: 1
user_id: 2, friend_id: 1, accepted: 0
```

(Notice that one party has not accepted yet)

I want to make sure that both people have accepted it so I don't accidentally load non-friends in with friends - so this and ONLY this should count as a proper friend;

```
user_id: 1, friend_id: 2, accepted: 1
user_id: 2, friend_id: 1, accepted: 1
```

(Notice both are accepted)

But I only have the following data being sent through;

```
user_id: 1
```

What's a smart way to fix this? I should use the returned result and re-query for each friend, right?

Comment: Looking at this, it appears to do exactly what you're asking of it, it should return 0 rows.  I even went and created the table you illustrated above (and a dummy users table with an id column to satisfy the query), populated both my tables with data, and got what I had expected to see.

Comment: It looks possible to design schema in a way that two rows are a not required for a friendship, one row should be enough. Any concrete reason to design it this way (two rows for a friendship)?

Comment: I think it's reasonable that a user initiating a friendship would wish to accept that friendship!

Comment: chrisg - Are you sure? Even with accepted=false as a default? Because when I do it, it returns non-mutual accepted requests. Sangharsh - I believe this is standard and I'm just missing something. Strawberry - And they do. But it's not reasonable to return a one-way acceptance as a 'friend', both parties need to accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With two rows for each friendship, you will have to join `friendship` to itself in order to find the freiendships that are mutually accepted. One way to do it is like this:

```
SELECT u1.*, u2.*
FROM friendship f1
INNER JOIN friendship f2
ON f1.user_id = f2.friend_id AND f1.accepted = true
AND f2.user_id = f1.friend_id and f2.accepted = true
INNER JOIN users u1 ON u1.id = f1.user_id
INNER JOIN users u2 ON u2.id = f2.user_id
WHERE u1.id = ...
```